# How to make a bootstrap sidebar collapse dont change the content width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How to make a bootstrap sidebar collapse don't change the content width?

please check my code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/dyaskur-the-typescripter/pen/ywbvby)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #fafafa
}

p {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none!important;
  border: none;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #7386D5;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #7386D5;
  background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
  background: #6d7fcc !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

@media(maz-width:768px) {
  #sidebar {
    margin-left: -250px;
  }
  #sidebar.active {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <nav id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <h3>BOOTSTRAP SIDEBAR</h3>
    </div>


    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
      <p>Dummy Heading</p>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">home1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">home2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">home3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Page</a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">page1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">page2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">page3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>

  <div class="content">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

      <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
      <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i> <span>toggle</span>
     </button>

      <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->

    </nav>



    <h2>Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 4</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <div class="line"></div>

    <h2>Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 4</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <div class="line"></div>
    <h2>Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 4</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <div class="line"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

I tried the code below but it makes the toggler button disappear.

```
#content {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

I want my sidebar be like on [this](https://framework7io.github.io/framework7-template-single-view/)

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps. added

```
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:1;
}
```

and add overlay with below css

```
.overlay{
  display:block;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    $('.overlay').toggle();
  });

  $('.overlay').click(function() {
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    $('.overlay').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body{font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
     background: #fafafa}
p{font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
 font-weight: 300;
 line-height: 1.7em;
 color: #999;
}
a,
a:hover,
a:focus{
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}
.navbar{
 padding: 15px 10px;
 background: #fff;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.navbar-btn{
 box-shadow: none;
 outline: none!important;
 border: none;
}

.line{
 width: 100%;
 height: 1px;
 border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}
#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:1;
}
#sidebar.active{
 margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header{
 padding: 20px;
 background: #6d7fcc;
}
#sidebar ul.components{
 padding: 20px 0px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p{
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a{
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 display: block;
}
#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #7386D5;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}
a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
a.download{
 background: #fff;
 color: #7386D5;
}
a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

@media(maz-width:768px){
 #sidebar{margin-left: -250px;}
 #sidebar.active{
  margin-left: 0px;
 }
 #sidebarCollapse span{
  display: none;
 }
}

.overlay{
  display:block;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <nav id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <h3>BOOTSTRAP SIDEBAR</h3>
    </div>


    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
      <p>Dummy Heading</p>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">home1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">home2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">home3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Page</a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">page1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">page2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">page3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>

  <div class="content">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

      <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
      <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i> <span>toggle</span>
     </button>

      <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->

    </nav>



    <h2>Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 4</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <div class="line"></div>

    <h2>Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 4</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <div class="line"></div>
    <h2>Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 Test 123 4</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```